# What is the best way to process a particular membership group to voluntarily sustain normal membership fees

Tags: discounts

More specially, we want to give our Over 65 members the option to pay the standard membership fees, rather than at a concessionary/discounted rate when they join.

We don’t want to create an entirely new membership group so were wondering if we could denote these members as "Sustaining Supporters" or similar on Civi when joining, while maintaining the Over 65 membership group unchanged in the CRM system. We could then have a back-end tweak that gives people who are NOT ‘Sustaining Supporters’ a discount.

Is this possible or is there a better/simpler solution.

Many thanks
Mike

Comment: Can you flesh out the above a bit more. DO you have a CiviDiscount set up if so how.

Comment: Also if you can clarify what you mean by Membership group as that isn't a specific CiviCRM term so leaves me a bit uncertain about quite what you have set up

Comment: Sorry, by Group I mean Membership Type (ie: Individual, Household, Over 65, Under 25.

Currently anyone who is over 65 years of age selects the Over 65 membership type which is priced at a reduced rate £27.50 instead of £55 (we do not have a discount code set up). 

We want to up date things so that anyone joining as an over 65 has the option of opting out of paying the reduced rate and wondered what the best way for doing this was without setting up another new Membership Type altogether.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Mike - i am missing something obvious - why not just 'let' them join as an Individual Member? Alternatively (untested) see if you can set up a Price Set Membership field (radio) with the same (Over 65) Memb Type listed twice - one with each price option